# SMPS powered DC motor inrush current problem

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor, inrush-current

I stumbled upon a problem when connecting a DC motor to a [SMPS](https://docs.rs-online.com/6d0b/0900766b816b4d81.pdf). It's a 20W AC/DC converter with an 12V output that powers some 12V DC motors the processor and some LEDs. I needed to speed up the most powerful of the motors so I added a boost converter on the lines of the motor to raise the voltage to 17 V. If I raise the voltage above 17V I encouter a problem when switching the motor on. Apparently the inrush current is too great and the SMPS shuts off and restarts, restarting the processor with it. The winding of the motor has a resistance of 15 Ohms and the running current of about 200 mA.

After searching the web I found 2 possible solutions to my problem:

1. LC filter after the SMPS where the C1 serves as a bank for the inrush current. The L1 is there to not cause the inrush problem when charging the capacitor C1 at SMSP power up (I have no idea about the right values for C1 and L1). The R1 represents the resistance of the motor winding (15 Ohm).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs5Zfq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. An [NTC thermistor](https://docs.rs-online.com/4976/0900766b816e7282.pdf) on the line of the motor. I'm unsure about the exact one to use as I am worried that the characteristic is not steep enough and would either have too low resistance when starting or too high resistance when the motor is running and thus slowing it down.

Would it make sense to use the combination of the two solutions?

How can I determine the appropriate values for L1 and C1? I have no idea how high the current peak is and how long it lasts, all I know is that the motor has virtually no mechanic load connected to it and can start easily.

I hope there is enough information, otherwise I'll try to add whatever is needed.

Comment: A buck converter is a step-down SMPS. It can't boost 12V up to 17V.

Comment: @brhans my mistake. I meant boost. I edited the post.

Comment: Can you get the boost converter to gradually ramp up the voltage to the motor? Start it at 12V by disabling the boost and then enable it one the motor is spinning?

Comment: @Cezerb, your project looks like some of the things I have been doing and some of my thoughts: (1) Using power MOSFET IRL540N driving DC motor 37GB528 motor: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94031/power-mosfet-driving-big-motor-problem, (2) MT3608/XL6009 boost converter with ICL/thermister NTC-5D7: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115057/discussion-on-question-by-animesh-lipo-battery-sparks-when-used-with-dc-step-up. / to continue, ...

Comment: / cont, ... (3) I am just an electronics hobbyists, also a newbie in ICL (Inrush Current Limiter). I know my NTC-5D7 is 5A, but I have no idea about its response time, so I am not sure if it is useful. If my ICL is not useful, I might try your L-C workaround. I also heard experts saying that a simple resistor can do the job, and suggest 300R. (4) I have a couple of SMPS including (a) 7.5V 26A (to simulate Lipo 16450s2), and (b) 12V 20A (my plan is to move up toy motor standard 12V to 24V industrial standard). / to continue, ....

Comment: / cont, ... I also have a couple of step down SMPS, including LM2596 3A, and ZK-JVA-12KX 12A. (5) Perhaps you can suggest something so that we can do some sort of pairing testing and development.Cheers.

Comment: @DavidMolony Unfortunately I can't. The added boost converter is only a temporary fix, I'm later going to use a faster 12V with higher power and I suspect I'll have the same issue. I'd like to limit the inrush current to get rid of this problem entirely.

Comment: @tlfong01 I've just found another solution that might work for you as well. I haven't tested it yet, but the idea is to slowly switch the MOSFET on using a capacitor between the gate and the source.

Comment: @Cezerb, Ah yes, that is called ***delay start or soft start***, which is used if the converter does not have internal delay start. I have checked that both ***MT3608 and XL6009 has built in chip soft start circuit**. In other words, if we use XL6009 to boost 5V to 12/18/24V, then we don't need any external soft/delay start circuit. (See my comment on the above referred chat record at Oct 15, 11:58 for more details)  Cheers.

Comment: @Cezerb, By the way, XL6009 has an 47uF external inductor, so your protection inductor of 1uH is very likely too small. I vaguely remember my GB37 motor takes about 350mA steady current and might be over 2A start/stall.

Comment: @tlfong01 This is why I asked about the L1 value as I have no idea how to choose the right value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115428/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-cezerb).

Comment: Pwm the MOSFET switch then from your micro, letting it freewheel through the diode drawn. Over a second or so ramp from 10%to 100%duty.

Comment: The inductor you'd need to solve this inrush would be rather large. Going on truly enormous. 1uH isn't going to solve it.

Comment: Yes, the SMPS datasheet says the inrush is 36A for 230VAC.